# How to pass multiple type of parameters in web api from angularjs?

Tags: c#, angularjs, http-status-code-404, asp.net-web-api2

I am struggling pretty badly in passing parameters to my web api.

There are two case I will list them both.

1. I want to pass a simple string param like this below

   ```
       [HttpGet]
       public string VerifyName(string name)
       {

           return name + "hi";
       }
   ```

For which I am creating a url like this in my angularjs controller.

```
var name = "hello";
            var msg = "";
            $http.get('/api/VisitorWeb/VerifyName', name).success(function (data) {
                 msg = data;
            }).error(function (data) {
                $scope.error = "An error has occured while adding! " + data;
            });
```

This keeps returning 404. Also

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:43516/api/VisitorWeb/VerifyName'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'VisitorWeb' that matches the request."}
```

1. Similarly when I am trying to pass a object it is giving the same result

My angular function

```
var loginModel = {
           UserName: $scope.UserName,
            PassWord: $scope.Password
        };

        var msg = "";
        $http.get('/api/VisitorWeb/VerifyLogin', loginModel).success(function (data) {
             msg = data;
        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An error has occured while adding! " + data;
        });
```

Web Api Method

```
[HttpGet]
    public string VerifyLogin(UserLoginDomainModel loginModel)
    {
        //do some business logic
        return "abc ";
    }
```

Response is 404.

WebApiConfig

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {


config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new   MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I am thinking there is some problem with the routing that is basic but some how not able to figure out what it is , Please suggest

Comment: best to POST complex objects to the API

Comment: First noticed that you not mentioned base url full url of your path it should include `localhost` as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049989/web-api-get-method-with-complex-object-as-parameter

Comment: For the first example if you change your controller method to accept and use an `id` parameter instead of `name`, you could then modify your angular call to `$http.get('/api/VisitorWeb/VerifyName/' + name)` and it should work. As others have pointed out, get does not accept objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This action:

```
[HttpGet]
public string VerifyName(string name)
{
    return name + "hi";
}
```

defined without attribute routing is mapped to the standard convention routing into the following URL:

```
http://yourhost/apiVisitorWeb/VerifyName?name=myNameValue
```

Because your route template `"api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"` expects a parameter named `id` (not `name`) to be part of the URI.

If you want to keep using your routing as is either use the above URI or change the name of your parameter into `id`, so you should be able to use this address:

```
http://yourhost/apiVisitorWeb/VerifyName/myNameValue
```

The same thing applies to your complex type parameters: in GET actions any complex parameter is expected to be bound from the URI as a collection of query string parameters. Your second action will bind to the following URI:

```
http://yourhost/apiVisitorWeb/VerifyLogin?UserName=userNameValue&PassWord=myPassword
```

But this is a bad practice for many reasons (security on the top). I strongly suggest you to turn this kind of action into a POST action, so you can send your model as the body of the request.

Answer (score -2):

Give this a try:

```
$http({ method: "GET", url: "/api/VisitorWeb/VerifyName", params: { name: name} }).success()
```